# I am trying to use groupby method for the following problem but can't figure out how to plot a bar graph for new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Display a dataframe of purpose and the total money spent for that particular purpose and plot a bar graph for the same
I am given a dataframe with the "purpose" and "money spent" columns I need to plot a bar graph for the new dataframe with total money spent.
I have created a new df with the following code but not able to plot the graph with it:

```
udp1=pd.DataFrame(udp.groupby("PURPOSE")["MONEYSPENT"].sum())
udp1()
```

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

just check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).

You can use this, just change the values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lab':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'val':[10, 30, 20]})
ax = df.plot.bar(x='lab', y='val', rot=0)
```

[image]

There are more examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498652/plot-bar-graph-from-pandas-dataframe) with matplotlib